# let your shirt dries ON you

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, let

```
Let your shirt dries on you.
```

Meaning: wearing a wet shirt to dry it. Would it be correct to use "on"?

Comment: It sounds fine to me, except that it should be: *Let your shirt dry on you.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. Thank you for this correction. Why can't we say "it dries"? You could have post it as an answer, I wish I could vote for you using an "humility" vote button!

Comment: I hope you didn't take my comment the wrong way. No humiliation intended, really.It was a common mistake among learners, and I'm sure I did that myself too, too many times than I can remember. :-) In the pattern "Let something [verb]", the [verb] should be in its bare form (or infinitive without to). As for why I didn't post an answer (about "let something dry on you"), I'd like to avoid answering this type of questions myself because I think your question will have a better chance to get answers from native speakers (which I'm not). Posting my answer could discourage them from doing that.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Ok I understand now, thanks for this! Such impressive person you are Damkerng, I'm amaze by the quality of your moral sense! That one made me laugh "No humiliation intended"! Shame I'd love it ah ah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @damkerngt. points out, `on` is fine, but the verb should by `dry`, and you have the meaning correct.